# how to read a file using ajax and django?

Tags: python, ajax, django

My Ajax code:

```
var upfile = $("#file-id").val().split(/[\/\\]/).pop();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/upload/',
    data:{"upfile":upfile},
    success: function(data) {
    if (data['success'] === "true") {

    }
    },
    dataType: 'json'
   });
    return false;
```

Django code:
   In simple form submit action `request.FILES.get('upfile')` works. I can read the content of file using `read()` But in ajax, it is not working. even `request.POST.get('upfile')` gives me the filename string.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: What Django view function provides the download?  You might want to post that code, also.

Answer (score 2):

It's normal, by default a form submitted with Ajax will not upload files. You need o have a look to some file upload jquery plugins (there's a few of them, I can not suggest one as I did not try any of these yet)

Comment: Yea, putting a variable in `data` is not going to do it.